# How Can I Create a MySQL Function to Check JSON Validity?

Tags: mysql, json, function, syntax, case

I'm fairly new to MySQL but I'd like to create a function to validate a JSON objects that are stored in my database tables.

I looked up information on creating a function, but must be missing something as I can't seem to get it to work. It doesn't seem like it would be overly complicated but perhaps I'm not using the appropriate syntax.

Here is my code:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION CHECKJSON( DB_NAME varchar(255), TABLE_NAME varchar(255),    JSON_COLUMN varchar(255)) 
RETURNS varchar(300)
BEGIN
    DECLARE notNullCount int; 
    DECLARE validJSONCount int; 
    DECLARE result varchar(300); 

    SET notNullCount = (SELECT count(*) FROM DB_NAME.TABLE_NAME WHERE JSON_COLUMN IS NOT NULL);
    set validJSONCount = (SELECT count(*) FROM DB_NAME.TABLE_NAME WHERE JSON_VALID(JSON_COLUMN) > 0); 

    CASE 
        WHEN (validJSONCount = notNullCount) THEN 
            SET result = CONCAT('VALID JSON COUNT: ', validJSONCount) 
        ELSE 
            SET result = CONCAT('INVALID JSON COUNT: ', (notNullCount - validJSONCount)) 
    END; 
    RETURN result; 
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

When I try to run this code, I get the following error message: 
"Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ELSE      SET result = CONCAT('INVALID JSON COUNT: ', (notNullCount - validJSONC' at line 14"

Any thoughts on how I might improve this code? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Since MySQL 5.7 you have a pretty and simple function for this:

> `JSON_VALID(value)`
>
> Returns 0 or 1 to indicate whether a value is valid JSON. Returns NULL if the argument is NULL.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-attribute-functions.html#function_json-valid

Comment: JSON_VALID(int) = 1,
JSON_TYPE returns a utf8mb4 string indicating the type of a JSON value. This can be an object, an array, or a scalar type, as shown here:
JSON_TYPE(int) = INTEGER,
JSON_TYPE(obj) = OBJECT, 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-attribute-functions.html#function_json-type

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a couple of ; and to end the case it should be END CASE.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION CHECKJSON( DB_NAME varchar(255), TABLE_NAME varchar(255),    JSON_COLUMN varchar(255)) 
RETURNS varchar(300)
BEGIN
    DECLARE notNullCount int; 
    DECLARE validJSONCount int; 
    DECLARE result varchar(300); 

    SET notNullCount = (SELECT count(*) FROM DB_NAME.TABLE_NAME WHERE JSON_COLUMN IS NOT NULL);
    set validJSONCount = (SELECT count(*) FROM DB_NAME.TABLE_NAME WHERE JSON_VALID(JSON_COLUMN) > 0); 

    CASE 
        WHEN (validJSONCount = notNullCount) THEN 
            SET result = CONCAT('VALID JSON COUNT: ', validJSONCount) ;
        ELSE 
            SET result = CONCAT('INVALID JSON COUNT: ', (notNullCount - validJSONCount)) ;
    END CASE; 
    RETURN result; 
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks Ben! I've created the function successfully but now It's not allowing me to call the function. Here's my code: CHECKJSON(evidenceStaging, INEGI_ROADS_20150430_MX_9, value);

I get the following error: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CHECKJSON(evidenceStaging, INEGI_ROADS_20150430_MX_9, value)' at line 1

Comment: Also when I hit the wrench under functions in the navigator for my CHECKJSON function, I get the following message from MySQL Workbench: 

There was an error while parsing the DDL retrieved from the server. Do you want to view the DDL or cancel processing it? 

Which leads me to believe there may be something wrong with my code- when I edit the function, it doesn't seem to like the 'WHEN'. Thoughts?

Comment: Ok, looks like you cannot pass table names into your mysql function... I've done a little more research and found that you can pass table names but you should create a stored procedure instead. I've tried to update my code to pass table names dynamically, but am still running into errors. Any suggestions?